# Write a nested dictionary having different keys(location, geo coordinates) to a csv file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, export-to-csv

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to write a nested dictionary containing address data and geo coordinates to a csv file. Here is the data that I want to write to a csv file.

[image: Data to be written to CSV file]

Code to write it to csv:

```
with open('dict_val.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
for key, value in js.items():
   writer.writerow([key, value])
```

The below is the csv output. The Key value pairs for the nested were part of the parent key. Also the csv file had 1 row skipped after writing each parent Key value pair.

[image]

Comment: The csv file suits for storing data like table. If you want to output this dictionary I suggest you save it into a json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment above that key:value, or dictionaries makes sense to save as json file.

But to answer your question about csv, you need to add in 1 parameter. Try:

```
with open('dict_val.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in js.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have saved the json data to a .txt file.Now i want to validate the json data that is saved in the .txt file against another json file.
Can someone help me how to go about it?